# How to use at::_upsample_nearest_exact2d in libtorch?

Tags: c++, resize, libtorch

I want to resize a tensor with the following code:

```
 auto size = img_tensor.sizes();
  int w = size[0], h = size[1];
  c10::ArrayRef<int64_t> hw_t({h, w});
  c10::ArrayRef<double> scale_t({384. / h, 384. / w});
  img_tensor = at::_upsample_nearest_exact2d(img_tensor, hw_t, scale_t);
```

below is the error dump

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::Error'   what():
> Must specify exactly one of output_size and scale_factors Exception
> raised from compute_output_size at
> ../aten/src/ATen/native/UpSample.cpp:18 (most recent call first):

if I change the code to

```
 int w = size[0], h = size[1];
  c10::ArrayRef<int64_t> hw_t({h, w});
  c10::ArrayRef<double> scale_t({384. / h, 384. / w});
  img_tensor = at::_upsample_nearest_exact2d(img_tensor, c10::nullopt, scale_t);
```

I got this error

> what():  Expected static_cast<int64_t>(scale_factors->size()) ==
> spatial_dimensions to be true, but got false.  (Could this error
> message be improved?  If so, please report an enhancement request to
> PyTorch.)

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the proper way to do it. Define a vector first then convert it to ArrayRef

```
  auto size = img_tensor.sizes();
  int h = size[0], w = size[1];
  std::vector<int64_t> hw_v{384, 384};
  c10::ArrayRef<int64_t> hw_t(hw_v);
  std::vector<double> scale_v{{384. / h, 384. / w}};
  c10::ArrayRef<double> scale_t(scale_v);
  img_tensor = img_tensor.permute({2, 0, 1}).unsqueeze(0);
  img_tensor = at::_upsample_nearest_exact2d(img_tensor, c10::nullopt, scale_t);
  //  img_tensor = at::_upsample_nearest_exact2d(img_tensor, hw_t,
  //  c10::nullopt);  // ok
```